# How to boost MySQL query on tables with millions of rows?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, query-optimization, large-data

I have 2 big tables in my database (`wp_frm_items` with about 3 million rows and `wp_frm_item_metas` with about 35 million rows).

I'm using the Query Monitor WordPress plugin and noticed that queries using joins and making counts are slow.

Some queries were taking more than 8s to finish! I fixed that by adding `DISTINCT` so that the query execution time is reduced into about 2s!

But still it is somehow slow for the page firing the queries to load fully.

I have 3 slow queries as detected by the Query Monitor.

1.6813s

```
SELECT DISTINCT it.item_id
FROM wp_frm_item_metas it
LEFT OUTER JOIN wp_frm_fields fi
ON it.field_id=fi.id
INNER JOIN wp_frm_items e
ON (e.id=it.item_id)
WHERE fi.id=110
AND ( it.meta_value='jack' )
```

2.7120s

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM wp_frm_items it
LEFT OUTER JOIN wp_frm_forms fr
ON it.form_id=fr.id
```

1.1344s

```
SELECT id
FROM wp_frm_items
WHERE form_id=10
```

I had added indexes (BTREE) on all columns that I'm using in my queries, but still queries are slow! I'm using `InnoDB`.

How can I optimize the query execution time in my scenario?

I had read this article https://www.percona.com/blog/2007/11/01/innodb-performance-optimization-basics about tuning some parameters like `innodb_buffer_pool_size=50G` (about 80% of the server 64GB RAM), `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2`, and `innodb_flush_method=O_DIRECT` but the queries get more slower with these parameters!

How to know what is the best values for tuning the `InnoDB` performance?

This is my current `/etc/my.cnf` file:

```
[mysqld]
innodb_file_per_table=1
default-storage-engine=InnoDB
performance-schema=0
max_allowed_packet=268435456
open_files_limit=40000
secure-file-priv = ""
```

Comment: meta_value belongs to the table wp_frm_item_metas (it). I had updated in the question

Comment: Incidentally, DISTINCT is unlikely to improve query speed. Use DISTINCT if you want DISTINCT rows, and not for performance gains.

Comment: These tables are from the [Formidable Form Builder](https://wordpress.org/plugins/formidable/) plugin.

Comment: From tables as large as the ones you mention, your first and third queries probably return very large result sets. There's no magic in indexing or in buffer sizing that can make that faster. The second query has a similar problem. It counts the exact number of responses in total to all your forms, ever. Counting takes time.  Your best bet will be to ask the plugin developer how to DELETE old responses after exporting them to make your tables smaller.

Answer (score -1):

Amend your query as:

```
SELECT DISTINCT it.item_id
           FROM wp_frm_item_metas it
           JOIN wp_frm_fields fi
             ON it.field_id = fi.id
           JOIN wp_frm_items e
             ON e.id = it.item_id
          WHERE fi.id = 110
            AND it.meta_value = 'jack'
```

And remove all indexes, except the PRIMARY KEYs, and add a composite index on some combination of (it.field_id,it.item_id,it.meta_value);

Comment: This is probably going to need an index on it.meta_value, fi.id is probably a PK and this might perform better using exists() instead of a join. But that's guesswork as the OP has not included any schema,

Answer (score -1):

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table.

The last query would probably benefit if `wp_frm_items` had `INDEX(form_id)`